# Memory warning when several apps running in background

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, xcode6

I am programming an app for iPhone and sometimes i get a memory warning while testing the App on my iPhone 5s. After some testing on this I found out that I just get the warning if I have too much apps open in the background. If I close these Apps I don't get more warnings.

My app uses something around 16 MB memory and I have to open a number of apps t get the warning but all apps I use during the day are enough to get the memory warning.

So what I want to know is whether I have to take care about it or can I simply 'ignore' it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app has never crashed because of a low memory warning, you probably don't need to worry about it. Although the device is running out of memory, it would first kill the background applications and when there are no more apps to kill, it will crash your application. So if your application hasn't crashed as of yet, you are ok for now.

Comment: if my app get crashed then how can i handle this sitution to avoid crash or improve the quality @Shamas S

Comment: Assuming your app crashes because of a memory crash, you need to see which parts of your app take up a lot of memory, and see if they can be cut down. You should also invest some time in learning to use memory management tools that come bundled with xCode.